# React hooks: useState not setting correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I created a setter function in a parent component and pass it down to its child:

Portion in question:

```
export default function Day({ dayInfo, props }) {
  var [timeOfDay, setTimeOfDay] = useState('');


  function TimeOfDaySetter(index) {
    console.log('index ', index);
    if (index === 0) {
      setTimeOfDay((timeOfDay) => (timeOfDay = 'AM'));
      return <Header as="h1">{timeOfDay}</Header>;
    } else if (index === 12) {
      setTimeOfDay((timeOfDay) => (timeOfDay = 'PM'));
      return <Header as="h1">{timeOfDay}</Header>;
    }
  }
```

That function is nested in a map function in the child:

```
     {Array.from(Array(amountOfRows)).map((row, index) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              <Table.Row>
                <Table.Cell rowSpan="2" style={tableStyle}>
                  {TimeOfDaySetter(index)}
                </Table.Cell>
```

But this is skipping the first condition?

Could anyone help why this is happening?

Complete Parent and component:

```
import { Header, Table, TextArea } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Day({ dayInfo, props }) {
  var [dayInfoInChild, setDayInfoInChild] = useState([]);
  var [timeOfDay, setTimeOfDay] = useState('');

  function setExactHourHelper(index) {
    return index === 0 ? 12 : '' || index > 12 ? index - 12 : index;
  }

  function TimeOfDaySetter(index) {
    console.log('index ', index);
    if (index === 0) {
      setTimeOfDay((timeOfDay) => (timeOfDay = 'AM'));
      return <Header as="h1">{timeOfDay}</Header>;
    } else if (index === 12) {
      setTimeOfDay((timeOfDay) => (timeOfDay = 'PM'));
      return <Header as="h1">{timeOfDay}</Header>;
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    if (dayInfo !== null) {
      var modifiedDayInfo = dayInfo
        .split(' ')
        .map((item) => {
          if (item.indexOf(',')) return item.replace(/,/g, '');
        })
        .join('-');

      if (localStorage.getItem(modifiedDayInfo)) {
        // setDayInfoInChild(function (dayInfoInChild) {
        //   return [...setDayInfoInChild, modifiedDayInfo];
        // });
        console.log(modifiedDayInfo);
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem(modifiedDayInfo, JSON.stringify({}));
      }
    }
  }, [dayInfo, timeOfDay, timeOfDay]);

  function TableLayout({ TimeOfDaySetter }) {
    var [amountOfRows, setAmountOfRows] = useState(24);
    var [textValue, setTextValue] = useState('');

    function handleChange(event) {
      setDayInfoInChild(event.target.value);
    }

    const tableStyle = {
      borderLeft: 0,
      borderRight: 0,
    };

    const colorOveride = {
      color: '#C1BDBD',
    };

    return (
      <>
        <h1>{dayInfo}</h1>
        <Table celled structured>
          <Table.Body>
            {Array.from(Array(amountOfRows)).map((row, index) => {
              return (
                <React.Fragment key={index}>
                  <Table.Row>
                    <Table.Cell rowSpan="2" style={tableStyle}>
                      {TimeOfDaySetter(index)}
                    </Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell style={tableStyle}>
                      {
                        <strong>
                          {setExactHourHelper(index)}
                          :00
                        </strong>
                      }
                      <TextArea
                        rows={2}
                        name="textarea"
                        value={textValue}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        placeholder="Tell us more"
                      />
                    </Table.Cell>
                  </Table.Row>
                  <Table.Row>
                    <Table.Cell style={(tableStyle, colorOveride)}>
                      {
                        <strong>
                          {setExactHourHelper(index)}
                          :30
                        </strong>
                      }
                      <TextArea rows={2} placeholder="Tell us more" />
                    </Table.Cell>
                  </Table.Row>
                </React.Fragment>
              );
            })}
          </Table.Body>
        </Table>
      </>
    );
  }

  {
    if (dayInfo === null) {
      return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TableLayout
        dayInfo={dayInfo}
        timeOfDay={timeOfDay}
        TimeOfDaySetter={TimeOfDaySetter}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: `useState` isn't supposed to be arrow function, `setTimeOfDay('AM')`

Comment: There are many minor mistakes in this code, but the biggest one is that you assume that `setState` is synchronic in (`TimeOfDaySetter`) which is not true.

Comment: @DennisVash Care to expound on them? I'd love the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should simply be setTimeOfDay("AM") and for the second conditional block setTimeOfDay("PM"). You are making it overly complicated by passing in a function that returns a string. While you could pass in a function that returns a string, for your setTimeOfDay to set it's string to, your function has a fundamental problem in that you are manually changing the state as well.

Notice in your function you have "timeOfDay = 'AM'". This completely defeats the purpose of setState and useState since you are manipulating the state directly.

The traditional setState does have use case where it can accept a function, but I don't believe that the useState does.

```
// Correct
this.setState(function(state, props) {
  return {
    counter: state.counter + props.increment
  };
});
```

And this function would not be useful for you right now anyways.

Also, in your useEffect. Even though, you have your use effect tied to [dayInfo, timeOfDay, timeOfDay], it is never actually modified, at least in the code that you have shown. So your Day component is only getting the change of dayInfo during the mount and not on a re-render.

Also, unless I am missing something, because your state is managed in your Day component and not each individual React Fragment, when you are calling

```
{Array.from(Array(amountOfRows)).map((row, index) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              <Table.Row>
                <Table.Cell rowSpan="2" style={tableStyle}>
                  {TimeOfDaySetter(index)}
                </Table.Cell>
```

You are simply changing the state of your Day component with each iteration on your map which will cause your react fragment to re-render. And so only the last condition would be honored since each fragment would re-render. It would be better to pass down props to a new component item instead of calling state on each iteration, make your state more complex to manage each fragment, or manage your state locally within each component.

Comment: Thanks Chris, originally the `TimeOfDaySetter` was just a function reacted to the map functions `index` input: `function TimeOfDay(index) {
      if (index === 0) {
        return <Header as="h1">AM</Header>;
      } else if (index === 12) {
        // setTimeOfDay('PM');
        return <Header as="h1">PM</Header>;
      }
    }`
Anyway now I see that I should just use a simple funtction.

Comment: Happy to help. Yes, I am not sure if you will run into any other issues. But I think remove that setting of state with each fragment produced will help.

Comment: And the dependency in `useState` should only be `useEffect(() => {.....}, [dayInfo]);` Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

As I see you pass arrow function as setTimeOfDay parameter:

`setTimeOfDay((timeOfDay) => (timeOfDay = 'AM'));`

Instead you should invoke setTimeOfDay as an usual setter, i.e.:

```
setTimeOfDay('AM');
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I appreciate it but that didn't work.

Comment: Although this code is uncommon, `(timeOfDay = 'AM')` return `AM` which is what the setter expects, also it doesn't solve the OP's problem

Comment: Hello Dennis, That is true, that it returns a string but notice that the OP, manually manipulates state by calling timeOfDay = "AM". However, I do believe the real source of the problem is in the map method and calling of set state each time on the day component to render smaller fragments. It will cause a re-render each time for each fragment and the last fragment will be the one that is honored.